# How can i connect Swift file and dart file?

Tags: flutter, plugins

I`m connecting Flutter and Swift so that i can use it in Flutter by connecting the public certificate api that works only in Swift. but, I have an issue and i want to ask a question.

What i want to do is import a Swift function through a channel to main.dart so that Swift code can work when a button is pressed in main.dart

How can i get func in Tilko.swift to main.dart

Here is that Structures
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gg2F.png)

main.dart is in ios/lib folder and Tilko.swift is in ios/Runner

Comment: Would you mind to share your `MethodChannel("..").invokeMethod` coding

Comment: static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('hem_cert_copy_plugin');

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `FlutterMethodChannel.swift`
and it look like

```
class MethodChannelFlutter {
    var controller: FlutterViewController
    var printerChannel: FlutterMethodChannel
    init(controller: FlutterViewController) {
        self.controller = controller
        printerChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "hem_cert_copy_plugin", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

        printerChannel.setMethodCallHandler {
            (call: FlutterMethodCall, _: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
             //Your handler
             //...
```

and your AppDelegate.swift should be like

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        
        let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
         MethodChannelFlutter(controller: controller)
        
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have create a working sample here
https://github.com/theamorn/flutter-template

In this file, I have 3 ways of connecting to Native SDK

1. calling Native and return value immediately
2. calling Native and pass to function and return from that function
3. calling Native and wait for the delegate to callback so we can callback to Flutter

First you add Flutter Channel in iOS
https://github.com/theamorn/flutter-template/blob/main/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift

```
private func initFlutterChannel() {
  // com.theamorn.flutter can change to whatever you want, just have to be the same between Flutter and iOS and unique ‘domain prefix. just com.theamorn is not enough
  if let controller = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(
        name: methodChannel,
        binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
    
    channel.setMethodCallHandler({ [weak self] (
        call: FlutterMethodCall,
        result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
        switch call.method {
        case "methodNameOne":
            if let data = call.arguments as? String {
                self?.callNativeSDK(data)
            } else {
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
            }
        case "deviceHasPasscode":
            result(self?.isDeviceHasPasscode)
            
        case "returnValue":
            if let data = call.arguments as? String {
                self?.returnValueSDK(result: result, id: data)
            } else {
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
            }
        default:
            result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
        }
    })
  }
}
```

`methodNameOne` use for calling Native function with a delegate which name should be consistent within Flutter

```
private func callNativeSDK(_ id: String) {
    // You can put any Native SDK in here, if the result return from Delegate
    let sdk = ThirdPartySDK(delegate: self, id: id)
    sdk.start()
}

private func returnValueSDK(result: FlutterResult, id: String) {
    // You can call any SDK in here if the result return immediately
    let sdk = ThirdPartySDK(delegate: self, id: id)
    return result(sdk.process())
}
```

To call from Flutter using this
https://github.com/theamorn/flutter-template/blob/main/lib/main.dart

```
final channel = MethodChannel('com.theamorn.flutter');
try {
    await channel.invokeMethod('methodNameOne', "12345");
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
    debugPrint("==== Failed to get data '${e.message}' ====");
}
```

Calling back from Native to Flutter, I call this function in Delegate of mocking SDK

```
extension AppDelegate: ThirdPartySDKDelegate {
    
    func onFinish(value: String) {
        // You can send anything into arguments, String, Boolean, or even Dictionary
        // Send data back to Flutter
        if let controller = self.window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController {
            let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(
                name: methodChannel,
                binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
            channel.invokeMethod("methodNameTwoFromSDK", arguments: value)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Waiting Value from Native

```
_waitingDataFromNative() async {
    channel.setMethodCallHandler((call) async {
      // Receive data from Native
      switch (call.method) {
        case "methodNameTwoFromSDK":
          _nativeValue = call.arguments;
          setState(() {});
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });
  }
```

You see that method name in iOS, and Flutter needs to be exactly the same otherwise they can't see each others.